# R: Illegal syntax accepted in plot function?

Tags: r, plot

The following code should not work, should it?

```
plot(1:10,1:10,main="",)
```

(There is an "illegal" comma at the end, right?)

Comment: You'll need to tag what language you're using here so that the right people can come look and answer. I'm sure its valid in some language somewhere and not in others. ;-)

Comment: Looks like MATLAB, or maybe R, but OP needs to clarify ASAP.

Comment: I do apologise - that's what happens when you only use one language!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of this statement is not illegal. R will use the parameter's default value if you provide an "empty" argument.

For example, the `rnorm` function takes three arguments. The latter two have default values:

```
rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1)
```

The expressions

```
rnorm(10)
rnorm(10, )
rnorm(10, , )
```

are identical. However, if you add an additional comma (and therefore an additional argument), the command will fail:

```
rnorm(10, , , )
# Error in rnorm(10, , , ) : unused argument ()
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg In the case of an numeric argument, the `plot.default` function is used. This function has many default values.

Comment: So why `plot(,5)` doesn't work but `plot(5)` does, while essentially it puts 5 in the y axis

Comment: @DavidArenburg The `plot.default` function has no default value for the first argument. If you omit the second argument, `NULL` is used by default. Have a look at the code of the function to see how this special case is treated.

Comment: Actually it more complicated than that, apparently the `xy.coords` comes in and tries to interpret it in a meaningful way, see Details in `?xy.coords` (just found out it my self)

Comment: @DavidArenburg In `xy.coords` the default value for `y` is also `NULL`.

Comment: I know, but when it is `NULL` and you run `plot(x = 5)`, `y` is actually getting the value of `5`, although you parsed it to the `x` variable

Comment: @DavidArenburg Have a look at the final `else` following `if (is.null(y))` in `xy.coords`. You will find `y <- x; x <- seq_along(x)`.

Comment: Yes, exactly, this is what described in the details